# Programmatically alignment?

Tags: android, checkbox, spinner, absolutelayout

I've attached one [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71y9r.png). In that image one checkbox and spinner are in undefined position. I'm using Absolute layout but also, i can't fix that to wherever. So, i need to set those by programmatically. Is this possible? Anyone help me. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Praveen It would be helpful if you put up your XML file. Any way absolute layout class has been deprecated try using frame layout or RelativeLayout. Absolute layouts are less flexible and harder to maintain than other types of layouts without absolute positioning.

Comment: Here is my XML file. Sorry i forgot to say onething to you. I've created that checkbox and spinner are created by programmatically. Are you clear? http://pastebin.com/SjmNkM1K

Comment: it says content is not available. Even if it has been created programmatically you still must use the exact coordinates to lock up your positions in absolute layout